# PredicateBuilder and LINQ to CRM

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, predicatebuilder

I'm trying to pull all the instances of a workflow that have ran (from the `AsyncOperationBase` table) with a number of predicates.

I know you can't use something like `myArray.Contains(x.WorkflowActivationId.Id)` so I'm trying to build a predicate dynamically with `PredicateBuilder`

Here's what I have so far:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Service.AsyncOperation>();

//Apparently, checking for null is suppose to prevent my issue from happening...
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Name == searchWorkflowDefinitionText.Text);
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.StatusCode != null);
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.StatusCode.Value == 10);
predicate = predicate.And(x => x.WorkflowActivationId != null);


foreach (Guid s in listBox3.Items)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.WorkflowActivationId.Id == s);
}


var r = (from c in xrm.CreateQuery<Service.AsyncOperation>().AsExpandable().Where(predicate)
                         select c).ToList();
```

But I end up getting the much LINQ to CRM dreaded exception:

```
Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.
```

As far as I know, to not get this error, you need to 'crawl down' attributes. Things like:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.WorkflowActivationId == s);
```

Have to be changed to

```
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.WorkflowActivationId.Id == s);
```

And also, the left hand side of the predicate must be a entity attribute. Again, as far as I know, my predicate satisfies those requirements so I am a bit at a loss here.

Any ideas ?

Comment: remember that CRM LINQ implementation has several limits, I didn't check but maybe this is one.

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes I know. Which is why I asked so I'd know what to blame: me and my misunderstanding of predicates, or the weak LINQ to CRM 2011 provider that doesn't really lets you access your data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I will need to circumvent LINQ to CRM's limits by doing this 2 part.

1st:

```
var t = xrm.AsyncOperationSet.Where(x => x.StatusCode.Value == 10 && x.Name == wkname).Select(y => new Service.AsyncOperation
                {
                    AsyncOperationId = y.AsyncOperationId.Value,
                    WorkflowActivationId = y.WorkflowActivationId
                }).ToList();
```

I really need only these two attributes for the moment.

Then I'll be able to have full LINQ access to `t`'s content.

```
var y = t.Where(x => myArray.Contains(x.WorkflowActivationId.Id)).ToList();
```